# How to mathematically subtract items in two lists in Python and only output those items which meet a condition?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have two lists that are already sorted from low to high:

```
A=['40','60','80']

B=['10','42','100']
```

I want to subtract each item in A by every item in B.  Then, if the difference between these values meets a condition, specifically, if less than 5, then delete both items from each list where the output should be:

```
A=['60','80']
B=['10','100']
```

**Sometimes lists are unequal in length, and sometimes there are only 1 item in each list

I have found many ways to subtract items in lists, but I do not know how to retrieve and delete the specific items in the specified lists, or they only subtract one item from each corresponding item in the opposite list

Using lambda:

if list(imap(lambda m, n: m-n < 5, A, B)) == True:

Using imap,sub

```
list(imap(sub, A, B)):
```

Using Numpy

```
M = np.array([A])

N = np.array([B])

c = abs(M-N)
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using numpy:

```
A = ["40", "60", "80"]

B = ["10", "42", "100"]

newA = filter(lambda a: all([abs(int(a) - int(b)) >= 5 for b in B]), A)
newB = filter(lambda b: all([abs(int(a) - int(b)) >= 5 for a in A]), B)

print newA
print newB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A_dict = {}
B_dict = {}

for i in xrange(len(A)):
  if A[i] not in A_dict:
    A_dict[A[i]] = []
  A_dict[A[i]].append(i)


for i in xrange(len(B)):
  if B[i] not in B_dict:
    B_dict[B[i]] = []
  B_dict[B[i]].append(i)

for x in B_dict:
  for i in xrange(6):
    if x - i in A_dict:
      B_dict[x] = []
      A_dict[x-i] = []

A_new_idx = []
B_new_idx = []

for x in A_dict:
  A_new_idx.extend(A_dict[x])

for x in B_dict:
  B_new_idx.extend(B_dict[x])

A_new = [A[i] for i in sorted(A_new_idx)]
B_new = [B[i] for i in sorted(B_new_idx)]
```

This has running time O(n log n) since the maximum difference you want to remove is 5 (a constant).  Should be much faster than naive O(n^2)