# Subtract items in a single list and retrieve items that match a condition

Tags: python, list, lambda, list-comprehension

I recently asked a question regarding the retrieval of differences between two lists that meet a condition, but I keep failing to alter the EXAMPLE LAMBDA EXPRESSION below to do the same for the items in a single list:

```
A = ['12', '15', '20', '30']

filter(lambda a: all([abs(int(a) - int(b)) >= 5 for b in List1]), List2)
```

Where my list is sorted and can have varied lengths.  The goal is to change the above expression in order to retrieve only those items with a difference TO ANY OTHER ITEM in the list is less than or equal to 5.

Where the output working on the list above should be:

```
newAList = ['12', '15', '20']
```

Comment: That equation was only shown as an aid to everyone so as not to start from scratch, my question relates only to the list shown.  If u prefer the lists are provided here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635995/how-to-mathematically-subtract-items-in-two-lists-in-python-and-only-output-thos?rq=1

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep the pairs of consecutive items that have a difference of at most 5? Or those items where the next item is at most 5 greater? Why is 20 kept in your example if the next item is 30, which is more than 5 greater?

Comment: What does "only those items with a difference less than or equal to 5"  mean?  Which items are you comparing?  If you have `['2', '3', '14', '15']`, what do you want to get back?

Comment: I want to keep any item in the list that has a difference to any other item that is less than 5.  I kept 20 because it is less than or equal to 5 compared with 15, not 30.
@DSM, the output should be everything as although the difference between 14 and 2 is >5, the difference between abs(14 and 15) is not

Comment: Are there duplicates?  What about a list of one element: does it pass or not?  (Tip: it's often easier if you write a code, however inefficient, which gives you the behaviour you want.  Then no one has to think about corner cases.)

Comment: Sorry good question, so single item lists would pass through the filter.  Sorry i do not have any working code to post.  The problem with list comprehension/lambda functions is I do not know how to specify the item in addition to the conditional statement

Comment: @Vince: a comprehension is simply a compressed syntax for a certain for loop, and a lambda function doesn't do anything that an ordinary function doesn't.  Once you've got that working, you can simplify it.  For example, it's still not clear to me whether if the list were ['2','10','10','20']` you'd want `['10','10']` or not.

Comment: @DSM: as the numbers in my lists are locations, there are no duplicates. But if the list was['2','10','20'], the output would be ['10']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shorter version:

```
>>> A = ['12', '15', '20', '30']
>>> [x for x in A if len(A) == 1 or filter(lambda y: 0 < abs(int(y) - int(x)) <= 5,A)]
['12', '15', '20']
>>>
```

Comment: Something like `[x for i,x in enumerate(A) if any(0 < abs(int(x)-int(y)) <= 5 for y in A[max(i-1,0):i+2]) or len(A)==1]` would be linear and not quadratic.

Comment: @DSM: Forgive me, but I don't understand.  What does "quadratic" mean?  I've never heard the term before and I am interested...

Comment: @iCodez: quadratic means "involving the second power".  Right now, if you double the length of A, your code will take not twice as long but four times as long (because for each element in A you filter on every element in A, so you do ~len(A)*len(A) operations).

Comment: Also, when I change the less than to a greater than (only for the sake of understanding this one-liner), it does not work.  Why does this matter?

Comment: @Vince: Well, that is because doing so allows for differences greater than 5 and every number in there has a difference with some other number that is greater than 5.  For example, 30 - 20 > 5.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I believe the following list comprehension should do what you are looking for. The key parts are:

- Using `any` instead of `all` to check whether any item exists that is at most 5 smaller or larger than the current one being looked at
- Using `enumerate` to ensure the condition ignores the item currently being looked at - you can remove the calls to `enumerate` and change the comparison to `0 < abs(int(a) - int(b)) <= 5` if you know there are no duplicates
- Using a list comprehension instead of `filter` to make it more readable, in my opinion (only just) - it should be possible to do the same thing with `filter`, however

The code:

```
>>> A = ['12', '15', '20', '30']
>>> [a for i, a in enumerate(A) if any(j != i and abs(int(a) - int(b)) <= 5 for j, b in enumerate(A))]
['12', '15', '20']
```

I bet this will be quite inefficient for any list much larger than this one, however, since you will be iterating over the list once for every item in the list. Hopefully it is enough to give you a starting point, however.

Comment: This is more than a starting point, thanks for working this out with me.  Thanks also for the explanations.  This works for multi-item lists, but does not work on single items.  But I will enjoy working that out.  Cheers

Comment: Also, when I change the less than to a greater than (only for the sake of understanding this one-liner), it does not work.  Where in the code does it change that?

Comment: @Vince What do you mean it does not work? It returns the whole list, as it should - there is an element in the list for every element that is at least 5 greater or smaller (12 <-> 20, 15 <-> 30, 20 <-> 30).